# coremltools converting GRU layer called with initial_state

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml, coremltools

In my Keras model I pass an initial_state parameter when calling the GRU layer. My app keeps track of the encoder_state and passes it back to the model when I want to predict on a new input.

```
encoder_output, encoder_state = GRU(latent_dim,return_state=True,name='gru')(encoder_input,initial_state=state)
```

All is swell when running inference with Keras but the problem comes when I try to convert to a coreML model.

```
0 : input_56, <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x7f5e21159668>
1 : input_57, <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x7f5e21159630>
2 : gru, <keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f5e2116a9e8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lbai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 752, in convert
    custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
  File "/home/lbai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 550, in convertToSpec
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/lbai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py", line 316, in _convert
    converter_func(builder, layer, input_names, output_names, keras_layer)
  File "/home/lbai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_layers2.py", line 1058, in convert_gru
    reverse_input = reverse_input)
  File "/home/lbai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/coremltools/models/neural_network/builder.py", line 1530, in add_gru
    spec_layer_params.inputVectorSize = input_size
TypeError: (None, 256) has type tuple, but expected one of: int, long
```

When I check the shape of this Keras layer I get what I expect. The first tuple is the encoder_input shape and the second is the initial_state shape.

```
print(encoder.get_layer('gru').input_shape)
>>> [(None, 1, 1536), (None, 256)]
```

Looking into the coreML code for convert_gru tells me it just takes the last entry in the input_shape as the input_size, which in my case is (None, 256).

```
def convert_gru(builder, layer, input_names, output_names, keras_layer):

  ...

  input_size = keras_layer.input_shape[-1]
```

Does anyone know how I can pass an initial_state to my GRU layer and have coreml convert it for me?

Comment: In Core ML you always need to pass in the state manually. Try converting the model without the initial_state argument.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Thanks! Any chance you can elaborate on passing the state manually to the coreML model? I can't seem to find any concrete examples.

Comment: To make a prediction with the Core ML model, you'd call `let output = model.prediction(input: xxx, gru_state: xxx)`. I'm not sure what the name of the GRU state input is, so it's probably not `gru_state`, but you get the idea: the state must always be passed as an input. The output of the model also contains the updated GRU state. You would pass that into the model the next time around, etc. In other words: Core ML does not keep any GRU state inside the model, you have to manage this yourself.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Makes sense. I'll give it a go. Thanks for the help.